# Creating a matrix of neighbors with Spark [`cartesian()` issue]

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, cartesian-product

I am a Spark beginner and I'm facing the following problem: I have a collection of items (let's suppose they are Cartesian coordinates or 2D point anyway) and I want to get the near elements for each of them. Deciding whether an item is near another or not is up to a function (let's suppose we want all those point whose Euclidean distance is less than a given value).

Of course, getting the neighbors of a point is trivial and I've done it. Just `filter` the items and that's all. What I can't do is getting them for all the points in the collection and I've no idea about how to do this efficiently.

I write here an example of the result I would like to get from a small dataset to make more clear my needs:

```
sourceData = [ (0,1) , (1,1), (0,0), (50,10), (51,11)  ]
result = [  
            (0,1) => [(1,1), (0,0)], 
            (1,1) => [(0,1), (0,0)],
            (0,0) => [(0,1), (1,1)],
            (50,10) => [(51,11)],
            (51,11) => [(50,10)]
 ]
```

Have you any idea about how to do that in an efficient way?

By now, I have tried this:

```
return sourceData.cartesian(sourceData)
            .filter(new PairNeighborFilter<T>())
            .groupByKey();
```

with

```
 public class PairNeighborFilter<T extends DbScanPoint> implements Function<Tuple2<T, T>, Boolean> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static double eps;


@Override
    public Boolean call(Tuple2<T, T> v1) throws Exception {
        return v1._1().distanceTo(v1._2()) <= eps && !v1._1().equals(v1._2());
    }


}
```

But I do believe it is a very inefficient way to do so. Moreover, later I need to count the elements for each key, which can be done only iterating over all the elements and counting them, which is another shame for the performance.
I would like to have a `JavaRDD` class as value of the `JavaPairRDD` instead of an `Iterable`, is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find neighbors efficiently, you'll probably want to avoid doing a full cartesian product, since it's an O(n^2) operation. One alternative would be to use locality-sensitive hashing to identify a smaller set of candidate point pairs, and then compute the exact distance between candidate pairs. (This is an "approximate" nearest neighbors approach, because it's possible that some of the true nearest neighbors for any particular point won't hash to the same bucket as the point in question.)

There are [a few ANN/LSH Spark packages](http://spark-packages.org/?q=tags%3Alsh) available for this.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This seems to confirm what I thought, i.e. an approximate approach is required in order to achieve scalability